# How can I install mods on the Mac release of Planescape Torment?

Tags: planescape-torment

So, GOG has gone to the trouble of releasing Planescape: Torment for OS X thanks to the wonders of WINE. Hooray!

Unfortunately, said release does not include the [core mods that are widely regarded as essential for playing the game today](http://www.gog.com/news/mod_spotlight_planescape_torment_mods_guide).

I happen to agree that *at a minimum* the widescreen and UI patch, and WeiDU Fixpack mods are essential these days, and am super fond of Unfinished Business and the Tweaks tool as well. Unfortunately, the method for installing all of these requires an executable windows application. Which, of course, means that I can't easily install them under OS X.

Is there any way to manually load/install these modifications, or are there mac versions of the core mods available somewhere?

Answer (score 19):

As user319078 says, the instructions at http://www.controlcommandescape.com/reviews/planescape-torment-review/ will work:

> 1. Download our [mod compilation pack](http://www.mediafire.com/?3x7ne4elq16o4qo), which contains all the mods listed above as of 6 August 2012, and unzip it.
> 2. Right-click on the Planescape Torment application, and choose `Show Package Contents`.
> 3. Double-click on the `drive_c` shortcut, and from there go to `Program Files/GOG Games/Planescape Torment/`
> 4. Copy all the files and folders from the compilation pack (from within the pstmods folder) here.
> 5. Go back to the Planescape Torment application and double-click it whilst holding down the option key.
> 6. From the window that opens, click “Advanced”, then “Browse”.
> 7. From the file browser, go to Program Files/GOG Games/Planescape Torment and choose the `Setup-PST-Fix.exe` file, then click `Done`, then `Quit`.
> 8. Double-click the Planescape Torment application. A text window will pop up, follow the prompt to set your language and other options (it can take a while to patch some of the files).
> 9. Repeat steps 5-8 for the files `Setup-PST-UB.exe`, `Setup-PST-Tweak.exe` (you can probably skip this one if you’ve never played the game before), `setup-widescreen.exe` (you’ll need to enter your screen resolution for this mod), `Setup-GhostDog’s-PST-UI.exe` (setting text to 80% bigger works well for HD resolutions). If at any point the icon just bounces in the dock, force-quit it a couple of times and try again (or logout and back in and try again).
> 10. Double-click the Planescape Torment application whilst holding down the option key, click `Advanced` and go to `Program Files/GOG Games/Planescape Torment` and choose the `torment.exe` file, then click `Done`, then `Quit`.
> 11. You can now play the game normally.

It's worth noting that there's actually a Mac version of some of the mods, such as [the widescreen mod](http://forums.gibberlings3.net/index.php?s=ae7f4cc4ff947b5582114038201a388e&app=downloads&showfile=869), although it is not code-signed, and in any case I couldn't get it to work.

But for every other mod, you can try the following approach:

- Download the specific mod you want to use. For this example, I'll use the [Ghostdogs_PST_UI_mod_v2.01.7z](http://www.shsforums.net/index.php?app=downloads&showfile=683) (although at the time of writing, that site appears to be down)
- Extract the files from the mod archive ([The Unarchiver](http://georiot.co/7e1) works)
- Right-click on `Planscape Torment` (sic) and choose `Show Package Contents`
  [image: Show Package Contents]
- Double-click the `drive_c` alias and browse to `GOG Games/Planescape Torment`
- Copy or move the extracted files into that folder, making a note of the name of the file with the `exe` extension (`Setup-GhostDog's-PST-UI.exe`)
  [image: Setup-GhostDog's-PST-UI.exe]
- Click the back button in Finder a couple of times, so that you're back inside the `Planscape Torment.app` folder.
- Double-click `Wineskin.app`
  [image: Wineskin.app]
- Click `Advanced` and then the `Tools` tab, and then `Command Line Shell`
  [image: Command Line Shell]
- In the window that appears, type `cd "..\..\GOG Games\Planescape Torment"`
- Type the name of the mod exe file (`Setup-GhostDog's-PST-UI.exe`) and press `return`
- Follow the prompts, if there are any (refer to other mod guides for specific options)
  [image: Wine Command Prompt]
- Repeat for any other mods
- Close all the windows
- Run the game as normal

If something hangs, click `Kill Wineskin Processes` in the `Wineskin Advanced` window and try again

As an added bonus, it's probably worth [updating the Wineskin wrapper](http://www.controlcommandescape.com/how-to/make-wineskin-games-run-more-reliably/) while you're at it.

Comment: One minor but important note for the superb instruction above:
In wineskin, tick the 'Use Start.exe' option. This will allow the terminal screen to appear so you can select relevant options. Without it the mods won't actually do anything. You can also install all mods using the [Test Run] utility rather than repeatedly quitting and restarting.

Comment: That comment above really should be added to your answer.

Comment: As of the current (17 September 2015) GOG version, with Wineskin 2.5.12, you can use Wineskin's "Test Run" option to run each executable without having to quit and restart, which saves a few steps.

Comment: Agree with the 1st comment. Another way to do this is to manually go to the folder using terminal, do `wine XXX.exe`, then the options will come out.

Answer (score 1):

Would the instructions included at the bottom of this page: http://www.controlcommandescape.com/reviews/planescape-torment-review/ help you out?  I'm afraid I'm not a Mac user, so I can't verify if the instructions there still work for modern OS X, but they appear to be the only ones to have actually tried to get the mods working and posted an explanation on the internet.  It also appears that the original locations of these mods are lost to the depths of Davy Jones's Router, so I doubt you'd be finding a mac version unless someone took the time to rip it from a mirror, unpack it, and re-make it for mac.